# thrift character encoding, perl to java

Tags: java, perl, character-encoding, thrift

I have a complex situation that I'm trying to deal with involving character encoding.

I have a perl program which is communicating with a java endpoint via thrift, the java is then using the data to make a request to a legacy php service.  It's ugly, but part of a migration plan so needs to work for a short while.

In perl a thrift object is created where some of the fields of the thrift object are json encoded strings.

The problem is that when perl makes the request to java, one of the strings is as follows (this is from data:dumper and is subsequently json encoded and added to thrift):

```
'offer_message' => "<&lt;>&gt;
&&amp;
\x{c3}\x{82}\x{c2}\x{a9}&copy;
<script>alert(\"XSS\");</script>
https://url.com/imghp?hl=uk",
```

However, when this data is received on the java side the sequence \x{c3}\x{82}\x{c2}\x{a9} has been converted so in java we receive the following:

```
<&lt;>&gt;\\n&&amp;\\nÃ�Â�Ã�Â©&copy;\\n<script>alert(\"XSS\");</script>\\nhttps://www.google.com.ua/imghp?hl=uk
```

The problem is that if I pass the second string to the legacy php program, it fails, if I pass the string taken from the dump of the perl hash, it succeeds.  So my assumption is that I need to convert the received string to another encoding (correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not sure that this is the right solution).

I've tried taking the parameters received in java and converting them to every encoding I can think of, however it doesn't work.  So for example:

```
byte[] utf8 = templateParams.getBytes("UTF8");
normallisedTemplateParams = new String(utf8, "UTF8");
```

I've been varying the encoding schemes in the hope I find something that works.

What is the correct way to solve this?  For a short time this messy solution is my only option while other re-engineering is happening.

Comment: yeah sorry, this is quite new to me.  The first string is a data dump of the perl hash and is converted to json then added to a thrift object and passed to java, the second string is what I receive on the java side.

Comment: I think the problem is that the string is encoded using UTF-8, and it shouldn't be. `utf8::decode($h{offer_message});` might help. (It would be even better if you decoded at the source.)

Comment: I thought perhaps the problem was with the thrift serialisation but I can change the encoding on the perl side I believe. Do you have an idea of a better encoding to use?

Comment: None.  It shouldn't be encoded before being passed to the json encoder

Comment: In fact, it may be double-encoded. What do you expect the string to be?

Comment: If I create a test in java where I copy the exact string as dumped on the perl side and pass that to the php, it works. I.e. the php correctly processes the string.  I'm going through the php code now to try and understand why.  So the best result would be a string the same as the data dump.  BTW, thanks for being so helpful. Do add an answer so I can accept it, it's a helpful discussion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117950/discussion-between-mark-and-ikegami).

Comment: The use of `Data::Dumper` could also be throwing a spanner in the works, because it escapes unicode characters automatically. You could `binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';` to ensure perl is outputting UTF8, and just print the string directly for your debugging. [Here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=759457) is a hack to try to prevent `Data::Dumper`'s auto-escaping.

Comment: it is indeed data dumper. I've found that I can pass anything through to php as long is it encodes to something below code point 007f, so it's not that the data from dumper works, it's that it just happens to encode below 7f. regardless, I've learnt a lot here, and will open a different question when I have a clearer understanding of the problem. Thanks for all the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in the end difficult to diagnose but simple to resolve.  It turned out that the package I was using to convert in Java was using java's default encoding of UTF-16.  I had to modify the package and force it to use UTF-8.  After that, everything worked.